# How can I have two $scoped variables in an Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, controller

I'm creating an angular app with a rails backend and accessing the database through api calls and receiving a json object.  I'm having trouble with defining multiple scoped variables within a controller.  I'm currently returning a variable markets which contains all markets in the database - this is my index.  I'm also trying to access a single market for the show page and this is where I'm having trouble.  Initially I had 2 separate controllers which worked but didn't seem correct.

Thanks!

Routes:

```
angular.module('farmCart', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
      })
      .state('markets', {
        url: '/markets',
        templateUrl: 'markets/_markets.html',
        controller: 'marketsCtrl',
        resolve: {
          marketsPromise: ['markets', function(markets) {
            return markets.getAll();
          },
          ],
        },
      })
      .state('market', {
        url: '/markets/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'markets/_market.html',
        controller: 'marketsCtrl',
        resolve: {
          market: ['$stateParams', 'markets', function($stateParams, markets) {
            return markets.get($stateParams.id);
          },
          ],
        },
      })
      .state('booths', {
        url: '/booths/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'booths/_booths.html',
        controller: 'boothsCtrl',
        resolve: {
          booth: ['$stateParams', 'booths', function($stateParams, booths) {
            return booths.get($stateParams.id);
          },
          ],
        },
      });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
  },
]);
```

Markets Factory:

```
angular.module('farmCart')
.factory('markets', [
  '$http',
  function($http) {
    var o = {
      markets: [],
    };

    o.getAll = function() {
      return $http.get('/markets.json').success(function(data) {
        angular.copy(data, o.markets);
      });
    };

    o.get = function(id) {
      return $http.get('/markets/' + id + '.json').then(function(res) {
        return res.data;
      });
    };

    return o;
  },
]);
```

Markets Controller:

```
angular.module('farmCart')
.controller('marketsCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'markets',
  function($scope, markets) {
    $scope.markets = markets.markets;
    $scope.market = markets.markets.id;
  },
]);
```

Comment: 2 separate controller would make sense. Can do it with one but seems simpler to separate the logic and resolve injections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resolves are named `marketsPromise` and `market`, none of which you're actually injecting into your controller. I'd recommend you use two controllers since it seems like the two states have separate purposes.

```
angular.module('farmCart')
.controller('marketsCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'marketsPromise',
  function($scope, marketsPromise) {
    $scope.markets = marketsPromise;
  },
]);

angular.module('farmCart')
.controller('marketCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'market',
  function($scope, market) {
    $scope.market = market;
  },
]);
```

Also, you may want to reconsider the name of the `marketsPromise` resolve, because ui-router will inject the data itself, not the promise, which may lead to confusion.

Comment: This is how I had the two controllers previously but a buddy of mine who is 'somewhat' familiar with Angular suggested I shouldn't have two controllers.

Comment: If I break it up into two controllers like I originally had it - should these two controllers be under the same file 'markets' or should the controllers and views have their own separate files?

Comment: Using one controller doesn't really make sense just based on the information you've provided. It doesn't matter where you store the controllers. They can be in separate files or in one file, but it's common practice to bundle everything into one file for a production build.

Comment: Thank you Anid - much appreciated!